# French Drain No Sump Pump

Tags: sump-pump, french-drain

My house is ranch style with no basement.  The garage and a small adjoining room are ground level with the other rooms built above them.  The house was built in 1970 and I have owned it for six years.

There is a French drain in the garage and also in a small adjoining room.  There is no sump pump.  We had heavy rains this summer and for the first time there was water coming out of the French drain along two walls in the garage and one wall in the adjoining room. There was no standing water but the cement floors had water stains from 12" to 18" wide.  It dried after a few days but the rooms still have a damp smell that they have never had before.

I had Roto Rooter look at it.  Their technician told me I need to have a sump pump installed and quoted me a price of $8,500.  He said he had never seen a French drain without a sump pump before and that if I didn't have one installed I would end up with a mold problem if I didn't have one already.

I am hesitant to follow his advice.

The house is more than 50 years old and has apparently functioned without a sump pump until now.  The Roto Rooter technician inspected the property and did not find any signs of water outside.  He asked if I had been experiencing any issues with the interior drains or toilets, and I have not.  There are no signs that there was ever flooding inside the garage or the adjoining room.  Do I actually need a sump pump?  That was the only solution he suggested.  He said there was nothing else that could be done.

Comment: A sump pump is needed to raise water to drain.  If the ground slopes enough it might not be needed, but the drain might be clogged.

Comment: Draining downhill is entirely feasible in many places, and is a lot more reliable than a pump. But it does not have the profit for roto-rooter that a new sump pump install does, evidently. And they require service rarely (if ever)  when set up that way, so perhaps that could explain the employee's unfamiliarity in a less harsh light, if you're so inclined.

Comment: make sure that your roof downspouts are draining properly into the storm sewer

Comment: Or at least make sure the water from your downspouts actually drains away from the house.